# Use VBA union function to conditionally add cells to range

Tags: excel, if-statement, range, vba

I am trying to add certain cells to their respective ranges depending on their interior colour using the union method. The code I am using is as follows:

```
For Each cell In EntirePossibleRange

    If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(132, 151, 176) Then
        Set AccessabilityRange = Union(AccessabilityRange, Range("B" & cell.Row)
    Else If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(244, 176, 132) Then
        Set ConsistencyRange = Union(ConsistencyRange, Range("B" & cell.Row)
    Else If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 217, 102) Then
        Set EfficacyRange = Union(EfficacyRange, Range("B" & cell.Row)
    Else cell.Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191) Then
        Set WiderImpactsRange = Union(WiderImpactsRange, Range("B" & cell.Row)
    End If


Next cell

End Sub
```

However the code won't run and throws up a syntax error. I cannot figure out what the syntax error is though.

Comment: It's `ElseIf` and not `Else If`. Also, unless your ranges start with a cell assigned,  you need to check if they are nothing before trying to union them with another cell.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I missed the ElseIf. How do you check to see if they are nothing? They all do start with no cell assigned.

Comment: Also, you are missing `)`  for all `Union` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a separate function to avoid repeating the same code checks each time:

```
Function JoinRanges(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As Range
    If r1 Is Nothing Then
        Set JoinRanges = r2
    Else
        If r2 Is Nothing Then
            Set JoinRanges = r1
        Else
            Set JoinRanges = Union(r1, r2)
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

then your code becomes (I'd use `Select Case` too ;)):

```
For Each cell In EntirePossibleRange

    Select Case cell.Interior.Color
    Case RGB(132, 151, 176)
        Set AccessabilityRange = JoinRanges(AccessabilityRange, Range("B" & cell.Row))
    Case RGB(244, 176, 132)
        Set ConsistencyRange = JoinRanges(ConsistencyRange, Range("B" & cell.Row))
    Case RGB(255, 217, 102)
        Set EfficacyRange = JoinRanges(EfficacyRange, Range("B" & cell.Row))
    Case RGB(191, 191, 191)
        Set WiderImpactsRange = JoinRanges(WiderImpactsRange, Range("B" & cell.Row))
    End Select


Next cell
```

Comment: I get a ByRef Argument type mismatch, do you have any idea why?

Comment: Your variables must be declared as `Range` objects.

Comment: I had originally them all defined in one line but separated them out, it is now throwing: Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Comment: I just realised its actually on the next bit of line that I added myself: Range("AccessabilityRange").Item(1, 1).Value = "Accessibility" Is that an issue with the range or with that code. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Would be clearer to use `Select Case` and handle for the ranges not already existing, ie.

```
For Each cell In EntirePossibleRange

    Select Case cell.Interior.Color

     Case RGB(132, 151, 176)
        If Not AccessabilityRange Is Nothing Then
            Set Accessabilange = Union(AccessabilityRange, Range("B" & cell.Row))
         Else
            Set Accessabilange = Range("B" & cell.Row)
         End If

     Case RGB(244, 176, 132)
        If Not ConsistencyRange Is Nothing Then
           Set ConsistencyRange = Union(ConsistencyRange, Range("B" & cell.Row))
        Else
           Set SetConsistencyRange = Range("B" & cell.Row)
        End If

      'étc

     Case Else
    'other option here
    End Select

Next cell
```